# How do I post a node that has its created field set to the past in a test class?

Tags: 7, testing

I am creating a test class using the framework of the core **Testing** module for a module that is supposed to autoexpire nodes some time after they've been created.

Nodes have two timestamp fields: `changed` and `created`.  I've tried to use the following code inside my test class (subclass of `DrupalWebTestCase`) to post an article that is supposed to have been created some time ago:

```
  // Post an article.
  $edit = array();
  $edit["title"] = $this->randomName(8);
  $edit["body[und][0][value]"] = $this->randomName(16);
  $edit['changed'] = 1397700000; // This is accepted.
  $edit['created'] = 1397700000; // This fails.
  $this->drupalPost('node/add/article', $edit, t('Save'));
```

The above code snippet produces the following error message when the test is run:

> Failed to set field created to 1397700000

Do anyone know how to explicitly set the `created` field to some specified Unix timestamp date for a node created inside a test class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access node create form using admin role created value is exposed using Authored Information...

[image]

So, You can able to set created date by creating user with administrator role for testing...

Please see implementation below..

```
<?php


/**
 * Tests the functionality of the Simpletest example content type.
 */
class SimpletestExampleTestCase extends DrupalWebTestCase {
  protected $privileged_user;

  public static function getInfo() {
    // Note: getInfo() strings are not translated with t().
    return array(
        'name' => 'Simpletest Example',
        'description' => 'Ensure that the simpletest_example content type provided functions properly.',
        'group' => 'Examples',
    );
  }
  public function setUp() {
    // Enable any modules required for the test. This should be an array of
    // module names.
    parent::setUp(array('simpletest_example'));
    // Create and log in our privileged user.
    $user = $this->drupalCreateAdminUser();
    $this->drupalLogin($user);
  }



  public function drupalCreateAdminUser(array $permissions = array()) {
    $roles = user_roles();
    $index = array_search('administrator', $roles);
    $user = $this->drupalCreateUser($permissions);
    $user->roles[$index] = 'administrator';
    return user_save($user);
  }

  /**
   * Tests creation of a Simpletest example node.
   */
  public function testSimpleTestExampleCreate() {
    // Create node to edit.
    $edit = array();
    $edit['title'] = $this->randomName(8);
    $edit["body[und][0][value]"] = $this->randomName(16);
    $edit["date"] = "2012-04-19 22:54:38 +0530";
    $this->drupalPost('node/add/article', $edit, t('Save'));
    $this->assertText(t('Simpletest Example Node Type @title has been created.', array('@title' => $edit['title'])));
  }
}
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: Nice approach, but I don't think limiting creation of nodes to the admin role would make this a fair test

Comment: @Clive, It will do for me :-). I don't care where they come from - I just want them to be old. But your solution looks OK as well, I'll keep it in mind if I need something more general one day. Impressed by the speed of you guys!

Comment: Agree with you clive :-) Just incase if some one want to set created date using admin role or where above field is exposed in create content type form..

Comment: @FreeRadical I've been off for a few days, my brain was crying out for something interesting to get stuck into ;)

Answer (score 1):

The value for `created` isn't exposed to the node form, it comes directly from [`node_object_prepare()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_object_prepare/7). So there's no way to override it using form values unfortunately.

The only way to adjust the created timestamp when it comes through a node form submission is to implement [`hook_node_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7). The easiest way to do this would be for your test to require a companion module, which implements that hook.

There is precedent for this: the core node tests include the [node_test module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!tests!node_test.module/7), which [implements `hook_node_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21tests%21node_test.module/function/node_test_node_presave/7), so [`NodeSaveTestCase::testTimestamps()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.test/function/NodeSaveTestCase%3A%3AtestTimestamps/7) can test that `created` dates can be overridden...

```
function node_test_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->title == 'testing_node_presave') {
    // Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
    $node->created = 280299600;
    // Drupal 1.0 release.
    $node->changed = 979534800;
  }
  ...
```

After creating the module you just need to declare it as a dependency in the `setUp` method, e.g.

```
parent::setUp('MYMODULE_test');
```

And you should be able to test properly.